# HTML and JS so buttons my button keep going away when i click it on them

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, visual-web-developer

I made a button which, when clicked, shows another button called `radiusButton`. When I click the `radiusButton` it seems to go away.

Also, how would I add another button so when I click `<button id="Slow">` 2 other buttons will pop up and make it where they both stay on screen even after clicking, and when I click another button like `<button id="Clear">` or `<button id="Active">` it will go away?

I tried looking it up, but still didn't find anything. I'm new to all of this,  just needing a little bit of help.

```js
function toggleRadiusButton() {
  var slowButton = document.getElementById('Slow');
  var radiusButton = document.getElementById('RadiusButton');

  radiusButton.style.display = 'block';
  slowButton.disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1 class="top-text">Traffic Control System</h1>
  <form id="form">
    <div id="container1">
      <img src="images/MTF.png" alt="mtff" class="MTF" />
      <form id="form1">
        <div></div>
        <br>
      </form>
      <hr class="Line">

      <button id="Stop" type="submit">Stop Traffic</button>
      <button id="Slow" type="button" onclick="toggleRadiusButton()">Slow Traffic</button>
      <button id="RadiusButton" style="display: none;">Radius</button>
      <button id="Clear" type="submit">Clear Traffic</button>
      <button id="Active" type="submit">Active Traffic</button>
      <button id="close">EXIT</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: The new buttons disappear because the ones you clicked are `type="submit"` so they submit your form and cause the page to be unloaded/reloaded. You need to change how your pages interaction with the server side works to achieve the behaviour you require.

Comment: soo can i just change from type="submit to type="button ? or  how would i go about this

Comment: Yeah that would work, assuming you don't need to actually submit the data in the form. Also, note that you can't have a `form` nested within a `form`, so your HTML is invalid